# Search for Pattern in Text String, then Extract Matched Pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to match and then extract a pattern from a text string. I need to extract any pattern that matches the following in the text string:

```
10289 20244
```

**Text File:**

```
KBOS 032354Z 19012KT 10SM FEW060 SCT200 BKN320 24/17 A3009 RMK AO2 SLP187 CB DSNT NW T02440172 10289 20244 53009
```

I am trying to achieve this using the following bash code:

**Bash Code:**

```
cat text_file | grep -Eow '\s10[0-9].*\s' | head -n 4 | awk '{print $1}'
```

The above code attempts to search for any group of approximately five numeric characters that begin with `10` followed by three numeric characters. After matching this pattern, the code prints out the rest of text string, capturing the second group of five numeric characters, beginning with `20`.

I need a better, more reliable way to accomplish this because currently, this code fails. The numeric groups I need are separated by a space. I have attempted to account for this by inserting `\s` into the grep portion of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***grep*** solution:

```
grep -Eow '10[0-9]{3}\b.*\b20[0-9]{3}' text_file
```

The output:

```
10289 20244
```

---

- `[0-9]{3}` - matches 3 digits
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: That would match on `10289 12345 RMX 67890 FOO 20244` - is that desirable?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' text_file

10289 20244
```

Prints next to last and the one previous.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$17 ~ /^10[0-9]{3}$/ && $18 ~ /^20[0-9]{3}$/ { print $17, $18 }' text_file
```

This will check field 17 for "10xxx" and field 18 for "20xxx", and when BOTH match, print them.